# Java classpath losing Main Class when multiple jar

Tags: java

Can someone explain me why when I got multiple jar in my classpath, java can't find my main class ?

if I try

```
java -cp MyJar.jar package.App
```

I got something i wannt, currently an error since some libs are missing

But if I try

```
java -cp lib/*:MyJar.jar package.App
```

or even

```
java -cp lib/*:MyJar.jar:. package.App
```

I got the error

```
Could not find or load main class
```

Comment: from which location you are executing this java program

Comment: You may need to quote that `*` to prevent shell expansion.

Comment: I use cygwin to simulate an UNIX env. Since at the end it will be used on UNIX.
I did try to quote it too... like this

    java -cp "lib/*:MyJar.jar" package.App

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this anyway. You should be using `java -jar` with the subsidiary JAR files named in the manifest of the main JAR file.

Comment: I tried this too but I got a bunch of jar to add, and I tried to add to my manifest <Class-Path>lib/*</Class-Path> but I don't think it's working.

Comment: "I don't think it's working" isn't a problem description, or indeed answerable in any way.

Comment: I tried it and got the same error that's why I don't think it's not working but i'm not sure that the problem is actually that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows environment the classpath should be semicolon separated:[classpath.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

So the command should be something like this:`java -cp "lib/*;MyJar.jar;." package.App`

If you are on Linux then try to enclose the complete path in quotes: `java -cp "lib/*:MyJar.jar:." package.App`

Comment: I'm on Windows but I tried both possibilities with cygwin. And everytime the error is the same. Wether I use colon or semi-colon according to the right OS

Comment: @BHMath .. are you sure you have single package.App class in all your jars and no conflict?

Comment: It's a scala class so in my jar in the folder package I got  App.scala  App.class  App$.class  App$delayedInit$body.class  App$$anonfun$1.class  App$$anonfun$2.class  App$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.class  App$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.class  App$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.class  App$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.class